# javascript pushState / onpopstate won`t work in combination with normal links on page

Tags: javascript, pushstate

I am fighting here with pushState and onpopstate events. Back forward buttons in browser works as expected ater i browse trough AJAX (a#itemPages) links. But if i click on normal links afterward and i go back by back button in browser, i am not able to move forward to normal links which should be in bworser history. I Am still able to move back and forward between "ajaxified" links, but normal links which should exist later in browser history simply disappear (forward button in FF slides out like there are no other items in history after actual item). Moreover, last clicked "ajaxified" link present in history two times.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a#itemPages', function(event){
    $(#plc).hide().fadeIn('slow');
    $.get($(this).attr('rel'), function(data) {
        $(#plc).html(data);
    });
    var stateObj = { URL: $(this).attr('rel') };
    history.pushState(stateObj, null, $(this)[0].href);
    return false;
});

window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    if (e.state !== null) {
        var prevstate = e.state.URL;
        $('#plc').hide().fadeIn('slow');
        $.get(prevstate, function(data) {
            $('#plc').html(data);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: needs more event.preventDefault()

Comment: unfortunately this doesn`t help. i gave it a chance...

Comment: sorry guys. there were another piece of the JS on the index page which manipulated history too. this brings the problem. closing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys. there were another piece of the JS on the index page which manipulated history too. this brings the problem. closing this issue.